# Twilio not working with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, twilio

I've been trying to send a text message through Twilio with a number I bought. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Made a Twilio account
2. Gone to "Phone Numbers" and requested a phone number

I then went to "account" and found my real account sid and authorization code. I then put this method in the `Meteor.isServer`:

```
Meteor.methods({
sendSMS: function(){
    twilio = Twilio('sid', 'auth code');
    twilio.sendSms({

                   to:'+7033502148', // Any number Twilio can deliver to
                   from: '+13348331065', // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
                   body: 'Test.' // body of the SMS message
                   }, function(err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio
                   if (!err) { // "err" is an error received during the request, if any
                   // "responseData" is a JavaScript object containing data received from Twilio.
                   // A sample response from sending an SMS message is here (click "JSON" to see how the data appears in JavaScript):
                   // http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#example-1
                   console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
                   console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "word to your mother."
                   }
                   });
}
               });
```

And.. I've called `sendSMS` (using `Meteor.call('sendSMS')`) from an external function in the client. I've verified that `sendSMS` is actually being called by using `console.log`. Can anyone tell me the steps that I'm missing here?

There isn't an error; it just doesn't send to the recipient.

Comment: There isn't an error; it just doesn't send to the recipient. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: add an else statement and try to console.log the err.

Comment: Have you checked for errors on Twilio's side? You can see errors collected here in your Twilio dashboard: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts or you can check out the full SMS log here: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/logs. Do either of those pages tell you anything?